# Mapping keys in JPA: Primary key is a foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Suppose you have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CREDENTIAL (
    USER_NAME       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    HASHED_PASSWORD VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_DATE       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE    TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY (USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_NAME) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (LAST_UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

One can see that the `USER_NAME` column is the primary key to the table as well as a foreign key. Yes, MySQL generates this table successfully.

The question is simple, how will I map this in JPA Entity? Should I have 1 id that maps to the `USER_NAME` column and another field `User user` that joins the `USER_NAME` column? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be:

```
@Entity
public class Credential {

    @Id
    private String userName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_name")
    private User owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by")
    private User lastUpdatedBy;


}
```

Note from own experience:

I would recommend creating a  [surrogate primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) of numeric type (beneficial from the DB perspective). You can enforce the uniqueness of the username by DB constraint.

Comment: Why use `@ManyToOne`? One user has one credential, hence why `USER_NAME` is a primary key.

Comment: ManyToOne is much easier to work with. Indeed, you can live with OneToOne, but I find OneToOne to be more difficult to manage. Also what if the application has several ways of authenticating the User?

Comment: It has, but the other authentication scheme are done through their respective 3rd party authentication, so there is no need to map it to `@ManyToOne` scheme.

Comment: Well, in this case I suggest not to introduce a separate Entity for credentials. Just put the fields into the User class. That will make things really nice and simple

Comment: @BuhakeSindi simply change the ManyToOne relationship to a `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, name="USER_NAME")` relationship and add the `@Column(name="user_name")` to the id property.

Comment: @AndreiI, and you'll get all the pleasure of maintaining OneToOne association. Usually OneToOne means that something is wrong in the application design (someone tries to "normalize" the DB too much). One thing to note that you can map Credential as an Embedded object and reduce the pain of OneToOne approach.

Comment: @Funtik there can be multiple problems that you want to solve by introducing a OneToOne relationship (DB performance (less data retrieved), module isolation), but this is not his question. Your solution is not complete and I tried to give an additional hint.